# What does $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ stand for?

Tags: notation

What does $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ mean?

I know $\mathbb{R}_+$ means *all non-negative real numbers*, but I have no clue what $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ means.

Comment: I don't think it is standard notation. Where have you seen it?

Comment: I would say: Look in the previous pages of that book.

Comment: Maybe it's a programming language... :-)

Comment: Since HELP never came back, maybe we can close this.

Answer (score 13):

It usually means the set of all positive real numbers, $\mathbb{R}_{++} = (0,\infty)$. Of course, there might be more symbols for this set.

Comment: Right, because $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ is ambiguous, as some authors use it for $[0,\infty)$ and some for $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: I have seen it used this way fairly often.

Comment: --in economics books.

Comment: But don't most math books use $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ instead?

Comment: Convex optimization also uses this notation.

Answer (score 7):

From my Course: *Probabilistic Methods in Finance*, we denoted $R+, R++$ like so:
$$R+ =\{x\in R : x\ge0\}$$ 
$$R++ =\{x\in R : x≫0\}.$$

Comment: What does $ x≫0 $ mean? Shouldn't it be $\mathbb{R}_{++} =\{x\in \mathbb{R} :  x>0\}$.

Comment: @john (3 years late, but may still be useful) It means "much greater than" (it's not precise); see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1516976/751299) for the "much less than" counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

Im not completely sure , but i believe it means strictly positive.
Thus not the negative reals NOR zero.

Well assuming the context is real numbers that is.

I believe it is used in countries where R+ is meant to include 0.
In most countries R+ does not include 0 , hence the extra symbol.

It might help to read over again to get an idea.