# What does this sign (<<) mean and how can I solve this question

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I simplify the top equation in the picture to the lower equation in the picture when the condition $t \ll \frac{v_t}g$ applies. I dont seem to understand the logic behind it :(
Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: hmm... I think your picture is missing

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I fixed the OP's formatting in order to show the image.

Comment: @NobleMushtak thanks.

Comment: The << just means if $t$ is much smaller than $\frac{v_t}{g}$.

Comment: Where's the lower equation?

Comment: @Raskolnikov I'm pretty sure the OP is talking about the $x=v\cdot \cos(\theta) \cdot t$ equation.

Answer (score 2):

The $\ll$ symbol means $t$ is **much** smaller than $\frac{v_t}{g}$. To learn more about this, check out [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516976/much-less-than-what-does-that-mean).

Comment: Yes sorry, I corrected it. I put the wrong picture

Comment: @Noobcoder Now, I am still having trouble understanding their derivation. I think someone else on this site will likely be better at understanding this than me since I am not that good at physics. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that $t$ here is supposed to be positive. It seems that the "simplification" being made here is
$$
e^{-g t/v_t}\approx 1- g t/v_t
$$
Notably, this is a good approximation whenever $g t/v_t \ll 1$, which is to say that $t\ll v_t/g$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation follows if you use a Taylor expansion to order 2:

$$
1 - e^{\frac{-gt}{v_t}}  \approx  \frac{gt}{v_t} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{g^2t^2}{v^2_t}  + O\Big(\Big( \frac{gt}{v_t}\Big)^3\Big) 
$$

You just have to slash off a remaining term
$$
-\frac{1}{2} \frac{g}{v_t} t^2 <<-\frac{1}{2}t << -\frac{1}{2} \frac{v_t}{g}. $$

Now, what does it all mean?
This is just the ballistic problem in a low velocity, high drag setting:

You have, for vertical motion, the equilibrium condition for the force

$$
mg = kv_t  \iff  v_t = \frac {mg} {k} 
$$

Actually   $\  \  v_{\infty} \ \ $ would be a better name.

Now, from the equations of motion

$$
m \ddot {x} =  - k \dot {x},  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \dot {x}(0) =  v\cos(\theta)
$$
$$
m \ddot {y} =  k \dot {y} - mg,  \ \ \ \  \dot {y}(0) =  v\sin(\theta)
$$

you get your solutions, which, for a short flight time
$$
t << \frac{v_t}{g}
$$
reduces to the familiar drag-less equations.