# Inequality that is stronger than the other(for smart people)

Tags: inequality

There's the notation in math which means (smaller) and another which means much smaller . Why is much smaller stronger that smaller ? I hope you understand what I mean because I dont know how to write their symbols .[image]

Comment: Smaller than : $<$. Much smaller than: $\ll$.

Comment: Thats right . These are them

Comment: I'm confused by your graphic.Note too that $\le$ means less than or equal not much smaller.

Comment: This is taken from prob1.10 from the book "A course in modern mathematical physics" For peter scekerz

Comment: I'm still confused by your graphic (and I don't have the book). For info on "much smaller" (which is NOT the symbol in the graphic) see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1516998

Comment: @tom  yes the first symbol is smaller but the second is much smaller (its more twisted than the above) to make it clearer thats why I wrote by red

Comment: "much smaller" is a double left arrow (twisted or not). The symbol in the graphic is "less than or equal"

Comment: Thats how they used it in the book . Okay thank you Tom :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63272/discussion-between-za-kh-and-tom-collinge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are referring to 
[image]
(available at link below)

Here the author is using the two  symbols (which I can't replicate with Latex) to represent two different **partial orders** (not to differentiate between less than and much less than).

P.S. the answer to the question may clarify what is going on. The partial order on line two is stronger than the first since $a \le x \text{ and } b \le y \implies a \lt x \text{ or } (a = x \text{ and } b \le y)$

https://books.google.co.za/books?id=ZuIgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PR4&lpg=PR4&dq=P.+Szekeres,+A+Course+in+Modern+Mathematical+Physics&source=bl&ots=rJ9u7UhlJm&sig=nSE68IYYcOzm36rABaui66STjUg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihrtj9m7vVAhXiJMAKHTlRCwsQ6AEIUTAJ#v=onepage&q=P.%20Szekeres%2C%20A%20Course%20in%20Modern%20Mathematical%20Physics&f=false)

Comment: Use `\preceq` for $\preceq$.

Comment: Note that with these definitions, "much smaller than" is really not a good way to describe $\preceq$ -- on the contrary given $q$ there are $p$  _arbitrarily close_ (according to the total order $\le$) to $q$ such that $p\preceq q$. More precisely, for every $s < q$ there is a $p$ with $s < p < q$ such that $p\preceq q$.

Comment: Also \prec for $\prec$..............  If the Q is indeed about partial orders (which  is something I cannot decide) then it is not about "much smaller than"  at all. .....+1

Comment: Thank you all. Thank you Tom! A friend of mine also gave me a nice example that is for the relation (a÷s) with b & y be values of s . So if we've taken a=1, b=2 and y=1.5 , then a÷b < a÷y , but not much smaller . It would be much smaller(not just smaller) if the relation were a÷(s)^n . So this rule is not universal but depends on the relation chosen .