# What does it mean when $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1 + x_2$ on $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R_{++}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

Does that mean that $x_1$ is all real numbers and $x_2$ is restricted to only positive numbers?

Comment: You sure whether it's $\Bbb{R_{++}}$ or $\Bbb{R^+}$?

Comment: It's $R_{++}$. From what I understand they're the same thing, but $R^+$ is more ambiguous on whether it means non negative or strictly positive, where as $R_{++}$ means strictly positive and $R_+$ means non negative.

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/190172/421580) thread will avoid any confusion for future visitors of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, $\mathbb{R}_+$ and $\mathbb{R}^+$ denote the set of positive reals. so you are correct, $f$ on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+$ means the first variable is a real number and the second -- a positive real number.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb{R}_{+} = \{x\in\mathbb{R} | x \geq 0$ while $\mathbb{R}_{++} = \{x\in\mathbb{R} | x \geq 0$. Thus it means $x_1$ is any real number and $x_2$ is any (strictly) positive real number.